# Transition from one modal VC to another without delay swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a basic scenario:

I present a VC modally using `self.present(, animated:, completion:)`.
Sometimes due to interactions in this modal VC i need to close one modal and open another one.
So i do the following:

```
weak var presenter = self.presentingViewController
let newVc = UIViewController()
presenter?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
   presenter?.present(newVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

This works but there is the annoying delay when switching the VC's when user sees the original presenter and can try to interact with it (to open other modals...).

I tried setting `animated: false` but that doesn't seem to work :/

I can't really switch to `UINavigationController` model for this because the modals i am presenting themselves are Page View Controllers and have the whole hierarchy of dependent views; the user is never going 'back'; so i'd really like to just present the new modal as quickly as possible...

**Update** My question is not about how to control or choose the animation. My questions is about having no delay between the modals.

Comment: You can replace the default animation with whatever you want.  See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrolleranimatedtransitioning

Comment: You can keep your view controllers inside different container views on top of each other, and when you want to switch between them you can make alpha of the one you want to show 1, and the rest 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in view controller architecture that switches views with no transition is the tab bar controller. So just turn your view controller into a tab bar controller — with no visible tab bar! To change to the other view controller just change tabs (in code). The change is instant.

This screencast makes it clear that this works as described. We present a view controller (yellow). Then we switch back and forth between two view controllers (green and yellow) as the presented view controllers, instantly. Finally, we dismiss whichever one (green or yellow) is showing. I'm doing it all with simple buttons but that's just for the demo; obviously you could do this however you like. It's the architecture that's the important thing.

[image]

Comment: I like this solution, it is plenty creative. Will see if i can re-architect the app like this, unfortunately that's a lot of code to change coz the yellow and green guys are both instances of the same for me, so i'd need to add this tab but only conditionally enable it :/

Comment: The yellow and green are instances of the same view controller class in my example too. Makes it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I can think only of solutions which would require you to handle the animations yourself

1. create custom modal transition using [UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioncoordinator)
2. add your controllers to container views as suggested by @muhammed-gül
3. present `newVC` over `self` and dismiss all presented controllers when you're done

And just a tip, you don't always need to wait for the `dismiss` completion closure, you can call this and it usually works, but still the underlying viewController is visible.

```
dismiss(animated: true)
present(newVC, animated: true)
```